# AdMob clicking strategy

Tags: android, admob

So, I'm making an Android app, and I have thought of a strategy to get more clicks:

The free version of the app works with ads in almost all screens. To access a certain feature of the app, the user must have clicked an ad in the last 24h. Also, by clicking an ad I "reward" the free user with 24 hours of no ads.

Is that a legit way of using AdMob? Does it go against AdMob ToS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this should anyway violate the Tos. It is upto you to decide when and where to display ads using Admob. Many softwares use a similar strategy to the one which you plan to use.

Answer (score 1):

Inviting user to click on Ads is a violation against AdMob ToS, but on the other hand inviting them to view an ad is OK
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342054?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287